# Xubuntu 16.04 notification area and indicators glitch

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, notification, panel

Recently updated my Xubuntu 15.10 to 16.04 and noticed that my panel missed tray icons for ktorrent. After some research I found trouble:
notification area (системный лоток) has ktorrent tray icon, but it hides when I add indicators (индикаторы) and appears again after I remove indicators:

[image: before deleting] [image: after deleting]

As you can see, the volume applet removes with removing indicators, it's not good.

I want to move the sound applet to the notification area and/or not have the notification area disappear when I add indicators. Is it mission possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delete Indicators plugin, install `xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin` with command

```
sudo apt install xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin
```

and add it to the panel. You will have your volume controls without messing with the buggy Indicators plugin.

There is also an [alternative version](https://github.com/equeim/xfce4-snw-plugin) of Indicators plugin which uses GTK2 and has a classic tray behavior, it might be free of bugs.