# Missing Wifi Panel/No Indicators XFCE

Tags: wireless, xfce

On a fresh install XFCE 4 does not have an option for adding a network panel. Other solutions suggest using the xfce4-indicator-plugin package but the indicator plugin does not show any available indicators and reports "No Indicators".

Answer (score 1):

In addition, you can check on which (if any) indicator plugins are installed, and get a full list of all available plugins, regardless of whether you want to install or delete them: (This is if you want to add/remove some plugins, but not get rid of the indicator entirely, of course. If you want to do that, see the related thread, linked at the end of this post.

```
sudo apt remove indicator*
```

Replace remove with install if you want to install, obviously. In both cases, you get of full list of all available indicator plugins, the only difference is whether you install or remove them. Both operations ask y/n at the end and wait for confirmation. Besides if you change your mind you can undo it, just repeat the command with the opposite verb.

To remove indicator, and let other XFCE panels/plugins handle things, see:

[Remove indicator entirely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/764418/xubuntu-16-04-notification-area-and-indicators-glitch)

Answer (score 0):

The reason the indicator plugin shows that is because there are separate packages that need to be installed before the indicator plugin can be used. Install xfce4-indicator-plugin indicator-network-tools indicator-network. I also installed the indicator-bluetooth package. If this doesn't work try installing indicator-applet indicator-application indicator-application-gtk2 indicator-appmenu because I never tested whether these were necessary. Reboot your computer to finish the installation.